# Get :checked value by Jquery Object

Tags: jquery

How to get the value from a JQuery Object? These are my radios:

```
<input type="radio"  name="radio_group" value="1">
<input type="radio" checked  name="radio_group" value="2">
<input type="radio"  name="radio_group" value="3">

var my_radios = $("[name=radio_group]");
```

This wont work (but i want it like this):

```
$(my_radios+":checked").val();
```

This would work:

```
var radio_value = $("[name=radio_group]:checked").val();
```

Is there a way to get the checked value from a Jquery object? Thx

Comment: Do you mean something like `my_radios.filter(':checked').val()`?

Comment: Have you tried `$('[name="radio_group"]').is(':checked').val();`?

Comment: @svenbravo7, your hint will not work, is() returns true or false, therefore you cannot run .val() on it, because is() does not return a jQuery-object. billyonecan 's comment is the right answer.

Comment: just perform a `val()` on the group name of radiobutton and it will give you the selected one.

Comment: @Yoda that'll just return the value of the first element in the collection, regardless of whether it's checked or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my_radios` is already a jQuery collection, you can just call [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on it in order to get the `:checked` element:

```
var radio_value = my_radios.filter(':checked').val();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxmpS/)

Comment: Thats a nice one. Thx for this!